# ROS1 working with map_server/change_map

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, mapping, map-server

I am currently working on my bachelor's thesis involving changing the map of a robot working in a multi-floor environment.

Right now, I want to change the current map published to /map topic. I already explored solutions involving killing and relaunching the map_server or running multiple map_servers and muxing between them, but I haven't been able to figure anything out regarding a ***change_map*** service.

I came across: https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/nav_msgs/html/srv/LoadMap.html, but I haven't been able to change the map successfully through the terminal no matter the argument I put in: [image: One of my attempts...]

I was wondering, am I doing something wrong or perhaps the service is not fully implemented in ROS1? (I came across some posts of people using a similiar service from nav2 in ROS2)

Any kind of feedback would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.